# Not able to load checkboxes checked in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Using `AngularJS v1.3.14` I am not able to load these checkboxes in default checked mode in Angularjs. As you can see I even used `ng-init="checked=true"` but not doing the job

```
<p>Add to wish list:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="wish" ng-init="checked=true" /></p>
<p>Send u result:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="result" ng-init="checked=true" /></p>
<p>include tax:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="tax" ng-init="checked=true" /></p>
```

ccan you please let me know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p>Add to wish list:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="wish" ng-init="wish=true" /></p>
```

Or:

```
<p>Add to wish list:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="wish" ng-checked="true" /></p>
```

A statement inside ng-init is simply an expression that get executed when the element is initialized. Inside ng-model you have the data binded to the element, so just set the data's default value to true using ngInit or ngChecked.